# SASS inspect() for array or another method how to output an array

Tags: sass

my question is how to make SASS function `inspect()` work with arrays or how to output array another way.

My basic example is this code:

```
@function z($layers...) {
  @warn "`#{inspect($layers...)}`";
}

.test {
  z-index: z("test", "test2");
}
```

which generates this error `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) for 'inspect'`

How can I output `$layers` variable inside @function `z`? Thanks

http://sassmeister.com/gist/a8b0610d63d23164328a

Comment: You do understand what `inspect($layers...)` does, right?

Comment: I considered it to work somehow like `print_r` in php does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `inspect()` function only takes a single argument.  By using the `...` notation, you're expanding the list into individual arguments to the function.  That's why it's complaining that you've supplied 2 arguments when only 1 is expected.

```
@function z($layers...) {
  @warn "`#{inspect($layers)}`";
}
```

Comment: Don't understand why you got downvoted as this kinda makes sense to me. Thank you